# convert char array into int 2d array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a char array of indefinite number of "couples" composed by index and value, separated by semicolon. Each index is separated from its value by a comma.

Example:

```
char srt[50] = "1,3; 2,4; 0,-2; 3,11";
```

("index1, value1; index2, value2; ...")

I want to convert the char array into a 2d int array, like this:

```
int num[4][2] = {{1,3}, {2,4}, {0,-2}, {3,11}};
```

How?

Comment: You need to parse this string. No easy way here.

Comment: There's an overflow in your code. Make it `str[21]`

Comment: Use `strtok_r` or `strtok` and `strchr`. Then Use `strtol`.

Comment: or `strtok` and `sscanf(str, "%d,%d")`...

Answer (score 1):

Hoping not to get downvoted for doing you homework, but I just found some time to code something.
The approach is to first count the (possible) number of pairs (which is the number of semicolons + 1) in order to reserve a proper array.
Then, use a loop with `strtok` to separate the pairs and a `sscanf(str, "%d,%d",..)` to read in the values. Note that the actual number of pairs might be different from the maximum number of pairs due to failures on parsing a pair:

```
int main()
{
    char srt[50] = "1,3; 2,4; 0,-2; 3,11";

    char* p=srt;
    size_t pairsCount = 1;
    while (*p) {
        if (*p++ == ';')
            pairsCount++;
    }

    int pairs[pairsCount][2];

    p = strtok(srt, ";");
    pairsCount = 0;
    while (p) {
        int key = 0, value = 0;
        if (sscanf(p, "%d,%d", &key, &value) == 2) {
            pairs[pairsCount][0] = key;
            pairs[pairsCount][1] = value;
            pairsCount++;
        }
        p = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<pairsCount; i++) {
        printf("%d,%d\n", pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A true 2D array `int pairs[pairsCount][2];`!  ( I would have used `size_t pairsCount = 1;`, and a space in `"%d ,%d"` but those are minor).